# Get input using tab instead of Enter key in C-Linux

Tags: c, linux

**Background:**

I am developing **linux-like shell** in **C**. The first and basic requirement is to get **infinite input** (probably commands like **rm kill** etc. , which will execute) from user & upon **Tab key**, list of possible commands must be output to the screen.

**Question:**

My question is that how to get the input upon **Tab Key press** instead of **Enter key**?

A quick example will be very helpful, since I'm a college student learning C as part of OS course.

Comment: You need to put the tty in raw mode.

Comment: If you are "learning C", implementing tab completion yourself would be rather challenging. You may want to read about [the readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) and perhaps use it in your project.

Comment: Search for `"C keyboard non-canonical mode tcgetattr tcsetattr"`

Comment: Did you experiment with http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc?

Answer (score 0):

You want receive already entered chars for autocomplete?
I suggest you to get each key press separately.
Thus, it will always be known that user have already entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
getchar()
```

or

```
#include <conio.h>
_getch()
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Console_IO

**Tab** is '\t' and **Enter** is '\n'

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\n')
        ++newlines;
    else if (c == '\t')
        ++tabs;
    else if (c == ' ')
        ++blanks;

    if (c == EOL) {
    printf("Lines: %d\nTabs: %d\nBlanks: %d\n", newlines, tabs, blanks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried this, I need to execute statement on tab press instead of enter key.

Comment: The code you posted detects keys/take input upon enter key press, I want the same but with Tab Key.

Comment: conio.h s for DOS and Windows.

Comment: `getchar()` input is buffered. Unless you are on windoze using `getch` (not recommended), you must put the keyboard in non-canonical mode using `tcsetattr`.

Comment: @mansoor67890 yes that's why I said that conio.h is for Windows. How did you manage to try it on Linux?